# How Do I make a navigation bar that leads to other html pages that I have created?

Tags: html, css, nav

Ok. So basically. I have a website for a project at school. But I need to have the home page, then split the rest into separate parts and put it into different pages. So that when the viewer clicks the respective button on the nav bar, it will load that part of my page. How do I make this work?
Each Category, i.e. Landforms, Climate, has to be on a separate page. plz help

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp is a good website to get Nav Bar Code From

Comment: thanks that did help. But it doesn't tell how to like, exactly do what I'm thinking. Like, do I code the entire thing, add the nav bar code, and then like,

Comment: When you start out building a page, the first thing I do is go top-bottom. Your Navigation bar will most likely be on the top, so I would start it first.

Comment: And a big part of coding is learning to understand the code written. So take the example and just start messing around with it. Learn something new.

Comment: if this helped you please mark it as Answered. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have for example pages: about.html, services.html and contact.html in same directory. Than you have same menu (like below) on all pages. Than you just change active class on `.menu__link`. A connection between pages should work.

If you want to load another part of the web to some active page, you can use `iframe` but it is a long time passé. Nowadays we are using AJAX, but it's kind of hard for some beginner developer. Use the first option I said. Hope I helped.

```css
.menu__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu__item {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 22%;
}

.menu__link {
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #7fbee6;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  transition: background-color .2s;
}

.menu__link:hover,
.menu__link.active {
  background-color: #06639f;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu__list">
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="./about.html" class="menu__link active">About us</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="./services.html" class="menu__link">Our services</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item"><a href="./contact.html" class="menu__link">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```